# PHP inserting data to mySQL two times instead of one and one time with data and with out data

Tags: php, mysql

IN PHP I am trying to save data in MySQL, but in my database, the records are storing the data two times. one time with data and other times with empty data.total two rows were creating.

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "demo";
    / Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }else {
   echo nl2br("Conected \n");
   }
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']);

     // attempt insert query execution
      $sqlin="INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', 
      '$email')";
     if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
     } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
     $conn->close();
     ?>
```

please tell me what are the changes need to be done in my code.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: there is no loop so you call the php file twice

Comment: Your code do not insert the record twice. It looks like your code is called twice from somewhere else, or the request is invoked twice. Check how exactly your code is invoked.

Comment: Also don't forget to use parameterised SQL and bind parameters instead of making your SQL dinamic. Otherwise you will have security breaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrated this script with HTML, make sure that you are not performing any action like button click twice which triggers this PHP script. If you click button 2 times, it will make 2 server-side calls. If you want to make sure that the problem is not with your PHP script, just replace the REQUEST parameters with static values and run as a PHP script and checks whether it inserts more than one row like below:

```
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'firstNameDummy');
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'lastNameDummy');
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'emailDummy');
```